# JsonWebTokenError: secretOrPublicKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

Tags: node.js, angular, oauth-2.0, google-one-tap

I have the below codes using @types/google-one-tap library in Angular 14 project:

```
  // @ts-ignore
    window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {
      // @ts-ignore
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: '85464xxxxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        callback: this.handleCredentialResponse.bind(this),
        auto_select: false,
        cancel_on_tap_outside: true
      });
      // @ts-ignore
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        // @ts-ignore
        document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
        { theme: "outline", size: "large", width: "100%" }
      );
      // @ts-ignore
      google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: PromptMomentNotification) => { });
    };
  }

  async handleCredentialResponse(response: CredentialResponse) {
    console.warn('this was called')
    await this.service.LoginWithGoogle(response.credential).subscribe(
      (x: any) => {
        console.warn(x, 'this is from the authentication google')
        localStorage.setItem("token", x.token);
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/logout']);
        })
      },
      (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Then this calles the auth service below still in my Angular app:

```
  LoginWithGoogle(credentials: string): Observable<any> {
    const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post(this.path + "/loginwithgoogle", JSON.stringify({ token: credentials }), { headers: header });
  }
}
```

Then in my server - node.js, I have the below implementation to verify the token:

```
app.post('/loginwithgoogle', function (req, response) {

    console.warn(req.body.token);

    const PRIVATE_KEY = 'xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx';

    console.warn('api called')
    const decode = jwt.verify(req.body.token, PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'), { algorithms: ['RS256'] });

    response.json({
        login: true,
        data: decode
    });
});
```

Upon calling the api, I get the below error:

JsonWebTokenError: secretOrPublicKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256

Any Idea what I might be missing out?

Answer (score 0):

woke up late but you need to use the public key not the private one.